# Is there a KUKA IDE?

Tags: programming-languages, kuka

I'm learning kuka krc robot language, so far so good, and am wondering if there is an  IDE for writing the code i want to program to the robot, something like

1. giving me suggestions if I mistype a variable
2. that suggest me methods available in the kuka language
3. maybe let me debug the code etc etc

any option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the official option which you can by from Kuka. It is called [Kuka Office](http://www.kuka-robotics.com/en/products/software/kuka_sim/kuka_sim_detail/PS_KUKAOfficeLite_Detail.htm). I am not sure about variable suggestions, but this can be used for debugging.

There is also [orange edit](http://www.orangeapps.de/?lng=en&page=apps/orangeedit) (currently in free beta) which many Kuka programmers use. This does have variable suggestions and also suggestions for methods/variables available in the Kuka language.

Another soluton is to use [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) withe the [KRL language plugins](http://www.robot-forum.com/robotforum/kuka-robot-forum/notepad-krl-plugin-by-henb3d-v1/msg68643/?PHPSESSID=cp5n01rcen6s13lkh5f43ecsg2#msg68643). This will give you variable suggestions (only your variables) and syntax highlighting and [formatting](http://sixdots.de/krlsourcecodeformatter/en/).

Comment: Indeed, it does not get much better than OfficeLite and a decent text editor for ordinary Kuka robots. Here is syntax highlighting and autoindentation for emacs as well: https://github.com/tommyolofsson/krl-mode